# Macro to loop through calculations across worksheets and paste values produces wrong results

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple macro to sequentially copy a column of input values, paste into a cell that is part of a large calculation (across workbooks), and then paste the output into a table (next to the column of input values). Somehow, the results that the macro produces are not the same as the values the formula produces if I manually insert the input value. If I run the macro twice, it does. Any help to resolve this will be much appreciated. My code is below:

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
Dim a, b, c, d As Integer

Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("E6").Value = "YES"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CalculateFull
Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("H9").Copy
Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("E14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CalculateFull
Sheets("Cockpit").Range("AA40:Ad47").Copy
Sheets("Cockpit").Range("Ak40:An47").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

For a = 0 To 22
Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("e13").Offset(a, 0).Copy
Sheets("US-specific assumptions").Range("e126").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CalculateFull
Sheets("Cockpit").Range("AA44").Copy
Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("f13").Offset(a, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next a

For b = 0 To 22
Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("e13").Offset(b, 0).Copy
Sheets("US-specific assumptions").Range("i126").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CalculateFull
Sheets("Cockpit").Range("AB44").Copy
Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("g13").Offset(b, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next b

For c = 0 To 22
Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("e13").Offset(c, 0).Copy
Sheets("US-specific assumptions").Range("L126").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CalculateFull
Sheets("Cockpit").Range("AC44").Copy
Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("h13").Offset(c, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next c

For d = 0 To 22
Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("e13").Offset(d, 0).Copy
Sheets("US-specific assumptions").Range("Q126").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CalculateFull
Sheets("Cockpit").Range("AD44").Copy
Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("i13").Offset(d, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next d

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity").Range("E6").Value = "NO"

'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I had to rewrite your code so that I could see what's going on. Here's what I finally looked at.

```
Sub YourMacro()
    ' 092
    
    Dim WsPit   As Worksheet            ' "Cockpit"
    Dim WsPPT   As Worksheet            ' "PPT_US Sensitivity"
    Dim WsAss   As Worksheet            ' "US-specific assumptions"
    Dim C       As Long                 ' loop counter: column
    Dim R       As Long                 ' loop counter: row
    Dim i       As Long                 ' loop counter: iteration
    
    Set WsPit = Sheets("Cockpit")
    Set WsPPT = Sheets("PPT_US Sensitivity")
    Set WsAss = Sheets("US-specific assumptions")
    
    WsPPT.Range("E6").Value = "YES"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("E14").Value = WsPPT.Range("H9").Value
    With WsPit
        .Range("AA40:Ad47").Copy
        .Range("AK40:AN47").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

    WsPit.Range("AK40:AN47").Value = WsPit.Range("AA40:AD47").Value
    
    For i = 0 To 3
        C = Array(5, 9, 12, 17)(i)         ' specifying columns E, I, L and Q
        For R = 13 To 35
            WsAss.Cells(126, C).Value = WsPPT.Cells(R, "E").Value
            WsPPT.Cells(R, 6 + i).Value = WsPit.Cells(44, 27 + i).Value
        Next R
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    WsPPT.Range("E6").Value = "NO"
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't rewarded for my effort. I can read but can't really test and I doubt that the re-writing alone cured any problems. My guess is that `Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("E14").Value = WsPPT.Range("H9").Value` assigns a new value to a validation dropdown - perhaps directly or indirectly (if the dropdown takes its list from a range the code alters) - that doesn't become effective until the second run.

'WsAss.Cells(126, C).Value = WsPPT.Cells(R, "E").Value` rapidly assigns different values to the same cell. The change will cause the sheet to be recalculated, quite without extra prompting. However, Excel might deem the calculation unnecessary while ScreenUpdating is disabled. So, if you want the result of the re-calculation in the next line of code, and Excel doesn't do it fast enough, slow down the macro execution by enabling ScreenUpdating. However, since you say that everything works fine on the second run I like my first guess better.

Comment: thank you - that worked perfectly. Using your code, without ScreenUpdating seems to have solved it. Appreciate the help!